# ¿Como mejoro este código con for o filter?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, foreach, map, filtro

Necesito solucionar la `precioMaquina()`, ya que no me devuelve la suma del precio de los componentes, ademas de que creo que se podria simplificar bastante.

Esta es la consigna: precioMaquina(componentes): recibe un array de componentes y devuelve el precio de la máquina que se puede armar con esos componentes, que es la suma de los precios de cada componente incluido.

```js
const ventas = [
    [ 100000000, 4, 2, 2019, 'Grace', 'Centro', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1500'] ],
    [ 100000001, 1, 1, 2019, 'Ada', 'Centro', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1500'] ],
    [ 100000002, 2, 1, 2019, 'Grace', 'Caballito', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard MZI', 'HDD Toyiva'] ],
    [ 100000003, 10, 1, 2019, 'Ada', 'Centro', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200'] ],
    [ 100000004, 12, 1, 2019, 'Grace', 'Caballito', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200'] ],
    [ 100000005, 21, 3, 2019, 'Hedy', 'Caballito', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200', 'RAM Quinston'] ]
  ]
  
  const precios = [
    [ 'Monitor GPRS 3000', 200 ],
    [ 'Motherboard ASUS 1500', 120 ],
    [ 'Monitor ASC 543', 250 ],
    [ 'Motherboard ASUS 1200', 100 ],
    [ 'Motherboard MZI', 30 ],
    [ 'HDD Toyiva', 90 ], 
    [ 'HDD Wezter Dishital', 75 ],
    [ 'RAM Quinston', 110 ],
    [ 'RAM Quinston Fury', 230 ]
];

const precioMaquina = (componentes) => {
    let totalMaquina = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<ventas.length; i++) {
        if(ventas[i][6] == componentes) {
            for (let e=0; e<ventas.length; e++) {
              for (let x=0; x<precios.length; x++) {
                  if (precios[x][0] == ventas [i][6][e]) {
                    totalMaquina += precios[x][1];
                  }
              }   
        }
    }
}
    return(totalMaquina);
};
```

Comment: Qué te devuelve precioMaquina? En cuanto a la simplificación... Porque no utilizas el nombre como una clave? por ejemplo: `const precios ={"Monitor GPRS 3000": 200, "Motherboard ASUS 1500":120,........]` y luego llamarlo como const["Motherboard ASUS 1500"]. De está manera te libras que hacer un el 3 `for`, aunque tienes que tener cuidado con esto ya que no es una clave identificadora y los nombres lo más seguro es que lo escriba una persona (Fallos humanos), así que para evitar errores añadiría una clave identificadora de cada componente (Dentro con un array de nombre y precio)

Comment: Que vendría siendo el parámetro "componentes"? es un array de partes? Es una parte y quieres calcular cuantas veces aparece en las ventas? Alguno de los números en ventas es un multiplicador de cantidad o no significan nada más?

Comment: Yo añadiría algo similar a lo que comenta José respecto al array de arrays de ventas. Interpretas los datos de manera posicional siempre es propenso a errores, ya que no está identificado claramente a qué corresponde cada dato. Lo mejor sería convertir ventas a un array de objetos. El hecho de plantear estructuras de datos no es tanto por ejercicio académico, sino por facilitar precisamente su manejo.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es un array con el precio de cada máquina de `ventas`, puedes en principio hacer un `map()` sobre las ventas, porque la relación es uno a uno, luego en el elemento de los componentes, puedes hacer `.reduce()` porque la relación es muchos a uno (la suma de los precios). Para buscar el precio puedes usar un `for` con un `break` que me parece que es lo mas óptimo, para que no itere sobre todos los precios. Ejemplo:

```js
const ventas = [
    [100000000, 4, 2, 2019, 'Grace', 'Centro', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1500']],
    [100000001, 1, 1, 2019, 'Ada', 'Centro', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1500']],
    [100000002, 2, 1, 2019, 'Grace', 'Caballito', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard MZI', 'HDD Toyiva']],
    [100000003, 10, 1, 2019, 'Ada', 'Centro', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200']],
    [100000004, 12, 1, 2019, 'Grace', 'Caballito', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200']],
    [100000005, 21, 3, 2019, 'Hedy', 'Caballito', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200', 'RAM Quinston']]
]

const precios = [
    ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 200],
    ['Motherboard ASUS 1500', 120],
    ['Monitor ASC 543', 250],
    ['Motherboard ASUS 1200', 100],
    ['Motherboard MZI', 30],
    ['HDD Toyiva', 90],
    ['HDD Wezter Dishital', 75],
    ['RAM Quinston', 110],
    ['RAM Quinston Fury', 230]
];


const preciosMaquinas = ventas.map(v => v[6].reduce((p, c) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < precios.length; i++) {
        if (precios[i][0] === c) {
            p += precios[i][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return p;
}, 0));

console.log(preciosMaquinas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo y releyendo creo que entiendo mejor. Cada elemento de "venta" es una máquina (un computador u ordenador de escritorio que arman con una combinación de piezas). Tú quieres el precio total de una máquina dado que consta de X componentes.

Lo que me intriga es que en tu función entras buscando por "componentes" y lo comparas con  `ventas[i][6]` que es un array. ¿No sería mejor en ese caso buscar por el correlativo de la venta?

Como sea, en el caso que busques una función del tipo `function calculaTotal(['pieza1','pieza2']) {..}` que te entregue el precio de un computador (por ejemplo para cotizar antes de comprar), tienes un error de base:

```js
let equipo1=['hdd','monitor'],
    equipo2=['hdd','monitor'];
    
console.log(equipo1==equipo2);
```

En javascript dos objetos no son iguales a menos que sean el mismo. Si comparas dos arrays tienes que recorrerlos o bien implotarlos, stringificarlos... etc

Acá resolví lo que yo creo que quieres hacer (que no me queda claro) de dos maneras, y hay muchas más. Ambas usan `reduce`.

El método `Array.prototype.reduce` se aplica sobre un array y tiene dos argumentos:

1. una función que recibe dos parámetros

   - El acumulador (puede ser lo que tú quieras)
   - El elemento del array del bucle actual.
2. el valor inicial del acumulador.

Por ejemplo puede usarse para sumar

```
let total = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((accum, numero) => {
   accum+=numero;
   return accum; <=== esto es muy muy importante
},0) // <== el acumulador empieza en cero
```

En la primera, filtro de entre la lista de precios aquellos que me interesan (los pasé en "componentes"), y luego hago un reduce sobre los que sí aparecen, con la lógica de la suma:

```
  total = lista_de_precios
             .filter(tupla => { 
              return componentes.includes(tupla[0]); // está entre los componentes?   
             }).reduce((acumulador, tupla)=>{ 
               // voy sumando al acumulador 
               acumulador+=tupla[1];

             },0);
```

Para filtrar uso Array.prototype.includes. Nada de iteraciones que uno se marea.

En la segunda función previamente convierto el array de tuplas [pieza, precio] en un objeto que es un diccionario del tipo

```
 {
   'Monitor GPRS 3000'     : 200,
   'Motherboard ASUS 1500' : 120
 }
```

En donde puedes buscar directo por el nombre en vez de iterar. Para eso recorres una sola vez el array.

```js
const ventas = [
  [100000000, 4, 2, 2019, 'Grace', 'Centro', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1500']],
  [100000001, 1, 1, 2019, 'Ada', 'Centro', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1500']],
  [100000002, 2, 1, 2019, 'Grace', 'Caballito', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard MZI', 'HDD Toyiva']],
  [100000003, 10, 1, 2019, 'Ada', 'Centro', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200']],
  [100000004, 12, 1, 2019, 'Grace', 'Caballito', ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200']],
  [100000005, 21, 3, 2019, 'Hedy', 'Caballito', ['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200', 'RAM Quinston']]
]

const precios = [
  ['Monitor GPRS 3000', 200],
  ['Motherboard ASUS 1500', 120],
  ['Monitor ASC 543', 250],
  ['Motherboard ASUS 1200', 100],
  ['Motherboard MZI', 30],
  ['HDD Toyiva', 90],
  ['HDD Wezter Dishital', 75],
  ['RAM Quinston', 110],
  ['RAM Quinston Fury', 230]
];

const usandoArrays = (componentes) => {
  let precioTotal=0;
  return precios.filter(tupla=>{
     return componentes.includes(tupla[0]); // está la pieza entre los componentes?
  }).reduce((accum, tupla)=>{
     let [pieza,precio]=tupla;
     accum+= parseFloat(precio||0,10);
     return accum;
  },0); 
};

// Acá me hago un arreglo de llave/valor con los precios
const preciosObj = precios.reduce((accum, tupla) => {
    let [pieza, precio] = tupla;
    accum[pieza] = precio;
    return accum;
  }, {});

// Suponiendo que componentes sea un array
const usandoObjetos = (componentes) => {

  return componentes.reduce((accum, componente) => {
    accum = accum + parseFloat(preciosObj[componente] || 0, 10);
    return accum;
  }, 0);
};



console.log('usandoObjetos me da:',usandoObjetos(['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200', 'RAM Quinston']))

console.log('usandoArrays me da:',usandoArrays(['Monitor ASC 543', 'Motherboard ASUS 1200', 'RAM Quinston']))
```

Lo importante es tener en cuenta que tu lista de precios puede tener 1000 productos, pero un computador no puede tener 1000 piezas. Significa que siempre es más eficiente filtrar el array mayor y luego si es necesario iterar sobre el array menor.

Iterar sobre ambos implica hacer el producto cartesiano de ambos, y no es buena idea.